# I am trying to pack a blend file but i keep getting an error

Tags: packed-data

I am trying to pack a blend file,[image] but I keep getting an error that the path of a particular item is not found. I tried deleting that particular texture and adding it again. Same error.

Comment: You're on windows and using Microsoft's "One Drive" remote file system.  It is possible that Blender isn't understanding how to get files from one drive or that there's a network error preventing Blender from reading the file across the network.

Comment: what do you suggest I do? Is there a way to edit the path?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I've not had to debug one drive problems so I'm not sure.  I assume the texture is working in your blend file?  make sure the blend file is saves somewhere.  Maybe try using the filebrowser to copy the files to somewhere on you PC's hard drive and then using those files in the blend file?